# Why is errorbar whisker length dependent on X

Tags: matlab, plot

I am running a simulation in Matlab 2015 which creates data each round, so I am plotting a number of single `errorbar` series individually. Here's a sample code and the output plot:

```
figure
xlim([0 30])
hold on
errorbar(1,2.0,1.9,16.5,'x')
errorbar(15,2.0,1.9,16.5,'x')
errorbar(25,2.0,1.9,16.5,'x')
errorbar(10,2.0,1.9,16.5,'x')
errorbar(30,2.0,1.9,16.5,'x')
errorbar(5,2.0,1.9,16.5,'x')
errorbar(20,2.0,1.9,16.5,'x')
```

[image]

The weirdness is that the whisker length appears to be dependent on my X value. As you can see it increases from left to right, even though I did not plot them from left to right. The single-sided width of each whisker is `0.01*x`.

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it? This doesn't seem like intended functionality. Ideally I would just manually set the width of each whisker, but I can't find a way to do that. There was a [function posted on the MFX](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22826-adjust-error-bar-width) a while back, but that was made for R2007b and no longer works. The `errorbar` series properties do not give any indication that the whiskers can even be affected at all. Any help here would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Post a reproducible example (that is, define `x` so that we can run the code)

Comment: @LuisMendo The x values are pretty clear from the plot, but I will add them.

Comment: you should be getting cross shaped error bars. Check the 'x' arg, I don't recall needing that in your case. Please plot one point, with spaces between the args and no 'x'. Also, check the help errorbar and you can always open the m file. Cheers.

Comment: @wbg I'm not sure what you mean. The `'x'` arg sets the center marker (around 2.0) to an 'x', rather than a dot or star. The 'x' may be the default, but I usually prefer to be explicit if I may change it elsewhere.

Comment: @Federico The width, or the length of the end-cap. You can see it in the figure.